# Struct Element with limited number or Values

Tags: julia

I want to create a `struct`

```
mutable struct myStruct
    id::string
end
```

I do want `id` to be a string, but I want it to take only 1 of 3 values (e.g. `"a"`, `"b"` or `"c"`). My idea is that could theoretically speed up operations.

1. Am I / would I be right about the speed increase?
2. Is this possible and how?

Comment: It sounds like an `Enum` would be a better fit semantically. I don't know if there would be a performance difference.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like a possible way. Can you elaborate it and make it an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any way to let `id` be a `String`, while constraining it to only have only one of 3 possible values in such a way that the compiler could take advantage of it.

However, if leaving the `String` domain is an option, you have a few possibilities. Let's try and benchmark some of them here. For the sake of the example, let's assume that this `id` field is used to test the equality between two `MyStruct` instances.

A possible (very minimalistic) generic implementation of such a type would be the following, where parameter `T` determines the type used for the id.

```
mutable struct MyType{T}
    id :: T
end

# Two MyType instances are equal if their ids are equal
import Base.==
==(a::MyType{T}, b::MyType{T}) where {T} = (a.id == b.id)
```

Now let's benchmark the equality operator in various cases. First, the base case using strings as identifiers:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> a = MyType("apple")
MyType{String}("apple")

julia> b = MyType("banana")
MyType{String}("banana")

julia> @btime $a == $b
  4.326 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
false
```

We would expect integers to be faster, and this is indeed the case:

```
julia> a = MyType(1)
MyType{Int64}(1)

julia> b = MyType(2)
MyType{Int64}(2)

julia> @btime $a == $b
  1.882 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
false
```

But perhaps the API is less convenient that way. Using an [enumerated type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.Enums.@enum) might more readable (users don't have to remember which value conrresponds to "apple"). It also prevents using any value that was not predefined, while keeping the same performance:

```
julia> @enum Fruit begin
           apple
           banana
       end

julia> a = MyType(apple)
MyType{Fruit}(apple)

julia> b = MyType(banana)
MyType{Fruit}(banana)

julia> @btime $a == $b
  1.816 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
false
```

A final option that might be worth considering is to use [symbols](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Symbols-1) for keys, which preserves (IMO) the useability as well as the performance:

```
julia> a = MyType(:apple)
MyType{Symbol}(:apple)

julia> b = MyType(:banana)
MyType{Symbol}(:banana)

julia> @btime $a == $b
  1.883 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
false
```

Nothing prevents anyone from building an illegal value such as `MyStruct(:cheddar)`, but it fits nicely in a context where strings are manipulated. For example, if you get the id as a string somewhere in your workflow, you can easily convert it to a symbol before constructing the `MyStruct` instance:

```
julia> id = "apple"
"apple"

julia> a = MyType(Symbol(id))
MyType{Symbol}(:apple)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Julia's typing system for this! No external libraries required.

```
abstract type Fruit end
struct Apple <: Fruit end 
struct Banana <: Fruit end
struct Coconut <: Fruit end

struct MyType{T<:Fruit}
    #could be some fields here...
end

a = MyType{Apple}()
a2 = MyType{Apple}()
b = MyType{Banana}()
```

This approach has two advantages:

- you are actually able to limit the set of values
- comparisons can be performed in the compile time so there is no time cost

Just an unbeatable performance benchmark:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime $a == $b
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
false

julia> @btime $a == $a2
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
true
```

#### EDIT

answer to the question by @Cameron Bieganek

> Do you have an opinion or guidance on when it makes more sense to define 
>   singleton types by hand and when it makes more sense to use an `Enum`?

My personal opinion is the following :

- whenever the type value is known already at the compile time always use singleton types
- whenever a small set of types is known already at the compile time (qualifying for a small union) use singleton times
- if you plan to implement different processing depending on the type use singleton types - broadcasting will be faster than a series of if statements
- when designing an API (your own Julia package) use singleton types since  you can use Julia's documenting features
- when lots of values (e.g. `String`s) that are being generated during the runtime and you plan to compare them for equality - use `Symbol`s. Good example is parsing a CSV file where column contains nominal values.
- in other cases consider using `Enum`s OR `Symbol`s - use the code readability as the criteria.

Comment: Do you have an opinion or guidance on when it makes more sense to define singleton types by hand and when it makes more sense to use an `Enum`?

Comment: @Cameron Bieganek thanks for the question. I tried to answer it :-)

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! This is already included in your "other cases", but I'd perhaps add more explicitly that when one plans to store a collection of values, enums or symbols allow to do it in a concretely typed container and should therefore probably be preferred.

Comment: @CameronBieganek I think singleton types make more sense when you're going to be (de)serializing the enums. I don't know a good way to construct an enum case from a string or symbol containing its name.

Comment: I guess this could make an interesting SO question. For sure we could find some ideas maybe through metaprogramming.